# Settings for custom wordpress widget not showing up

Tags: wordpress, widget, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to extend the default gallery widget in wordpress (v5.1.1) for a child theme. The widget shows up in the "Widgets" section of the dashboard, but the form fields never show up to edit the widget settings. Below shows the behavior with the default gallery widget, and then my widget (called "Extended Gallery").

[image: Picture]

What I did: I copied and pasted the content of /wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-media-gallery.php into a file in my child theme called extended-gallery.php. The two files are the exact same except for at the beginning of extended-gallery.php where I changed the class name and handle.

[see class-wp-widget-media-gallery.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.1.1/src/wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-media-gallery.php)

changes I made in extended-gallery.php:

```
class Extended_Gallery extends WP_Widget_Media {

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @since 4.9.0
     */
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            'media_gallery_extended',
            __( 'Extended Gallery' ),
            array(
                'description' => __( 'Displays an image gallery.' ),
                'mime_type'   => 'image',
            )
        );
```

In functions.php, I register extended-gallery.php

```
<?php

//custom widgets

require_once("extended-gallery.php");
add_action("widgets_init", "custom_widgets_init");

function custom_widgets_init(){
  register_widget("Extended_Gallery");
}

// add custom style

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'parent-style'; 

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}

?>
```

How do I get the settings fields for my custom widget to work the same way as the default gallery widget? If I add additional fields, will it screw it up?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about creating a new plugin on wordpress.
You should 'register' your widgets. Like as following.

```
add_action( 'elementor/widgets/widgets_registered', [ $this, 'init_widgets' ] );
```

And you should activate your new plugin.
Good luck.